# "Existing with probability tending to $1$" means...?

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

From Wasserman, *All of Statistics*, Theorem 9.6:

> Let $\hat{\theta}_n$ denote the method of moments estimator. Under
>   appropriate conditions on the model, the following statements hold:
>
> 1. The estimate $\hat{\theta}_n$ exists with probability tending to $1$.

What does this precisely mean? Searching has not helped me find the precise meaning of this statement.

Additional context: $\hat{\theta}_n$ is calculated according to the method of moments to estimate $\theta$. So, for instance, if a probability distribution has one parameter and we have an iid sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$ following such a probability distribution, we would set $\mathbb{E}[X] = \bar{X}$, $\bar{X}$ being the arithmetic average of $X_1, \dots, X_n$. $\mathbb{E}[X]$ would likely be dependent on $\theta$; such a $\theta$ which solves the above equation is $\hat{\theta}_n$. With $k$ parameters $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_k$, we set $\mathbb{E}[X^j] = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^{j}$ for $j = 1, \dots, k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, your additional context clarified matters.

Consider the space of all sequences $S$ of randoms drawn (each member of the sequence independently) from the distribution of interest. Let $\hat{\theta}_n[S]$ be the estimator based on the first $n$ elements of $S$. Now for most distributions we ordinarily work with, there is some number $\theta$ such that the set of sequences for which $\lim_{n\to\infty} \hat{\theta}_n[S] \neq \theta$ has measure zero.  So $\lim_{n\to\infty} \hat{\theta}_n[S]$ "Almost Surely" exists and is equal to that $\theta$.  (There are some long-tailed distributions for which this property does not hold.)

While the limit Almost Surely is $\theta$, the limit for any given sequence need not be $\theta$.

For example, for the unit normal distribution, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \hat{\theta}_n[S] = 0$ a.s.  But imagine the sequence of randoms $\{1,1,1,1,\ldots\}$.  This sequence is *possible* (although the probability of the union of all such sequences is vanishingly small). And that sequence will have the wrong limit for the estimator. In fact, for the sequence $\{1,4,9,16,\ldots\}$, the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} \hat{\theta}_n[S]$ doesn't exist.

Nonetheless, if the "appropriate conditions on the model" hold, the method of estimation is useful because the limit "exists with probability one."

Comment: I didn't realize it did, thank you! So this looks like something that will be studied in greater depth once I get to the measure-theoretic treatment...

Answer (score 1):

You have a probability $p_n$ that $\hat{\theta_n}$ exists, and $\lim_{n\to +\infty} p_n =1$

Comment: I don't think this is right.  $n$ can't mean the number of points in the sample, because the estimator exists for any finite set of samples. Perhaps $n$ refers to the moment being estimated?

Comment: @MarkFischler Additional context provided.

Answer (score 1):

Additional context would be helpful, but I assume that there's a chance that $\hat\theta_n$ isn't well defined in whatever set-up you have. Then it means that if we let $p_n$ be the probability that $\hat\theta_n$ exists, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}p_n=1$$

Comment: $\hat{\theta}_n$ is calculated according to the method of moments to estimate $\theta$. So, for instance, if a probability distribution has one parameter and we have an iid sample $X_1, \dots, X_n$ following such a probability distribution, we would set $\mathbb{E}[X] = \bar{X}$, $\bar{X}$ being the arithmetic average of $X_1, \dots, X_n$. $\mathbb{E}[X]$ would likely be dependent on $\theta$; such a $\theta$ which solves the above equation is $\hat{\theta}_n$. With $k$ parameters $\theta_1, \dots, \theta_k$, we set $\mathbb{E}[X^j] = \dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^{j}$ for $j = 1, \dots, k$.